# Is it true that given $x\in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$, $y\in \mathbb Q$, this expression is always negative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x\in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$, $y\in \mathbb Q$. Is it true that

$\frac{x^{4}-4x^{3}y+6x^{2}y^{2}-4xy^{3}+y^{4}}{-x^{2}+xy-y^{2}} < 0$

Comment: Is $\Bbb{I}$ the irrationals, the pure imaginaries, or the unit interval?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity, irrationals.

Comment: Hint : The numerator is $(x-y)^4$, hence positive. Hence you only have to show that the denominator is negative, which should be not too difficult.

Comment: Following @Peter hint: the denominator is $(x-y)^2-xy$, which reduces the problem to check whether   $(x-y)^2>-xy$. Note that one side is always non-negative, so you can study the cases where $x$ and $y$ have different signs to make $-xy\geq 0$, because in any other case it is trivial.

Comment: Or you use $$-x^2+xy-y^2=-(x-y/2)^2-3/4y^2$$

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! just didn't see the simple factoring with the top.

Comment: As $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ are dense in $\mathbb R$ and thats a continuous expression, I'd say the restrictions to $x$ being irrational is irrelevent (unless it is to say $x \ne 0$) as is the restriction of $y$ to the rationals (unless it is to say say $y$ can't be an irrational root of something that will render a value of $0$.

Comment: The restriction was to ensure a strict inequality, it makes sense in the context that this example is taken from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true, and this has nothing to do with where $x$ or $y$ live,  – they can be arbitrary, but *distinct* real numbers:
$$\frac{x^{4}-4x^{3}y+6x^{2}y^{2}-4xy^{3}+y^{4}}{-x^{2}+xy-y^{2}}=-\frac{(x-y)^{4}}{x^{2}-xy+y^{2}}.$$
The numerator of the latter fraction is positive as soon as $x\ne y$ (which is the case if $x\in\mathbf R \setminus \mathbf Q$ and $y\in\mathbf Q$), and it is  well known that the denominator is positive (to see it, set  $y=tx$: $x^2-xy+y^2=x^2(1-t+t^2)$; the quadratic in $t$ has no real roots, hence has the sign of its leading coefficient).

Comment: @Norse: Thank you for your edit. It seems I had mistyped some `$` \ I should check ùore carefully before posting. For the notation of number sets, however, I stck to the old style boldface (as in Bourbaki). For me (and others…), the *blackbord boldface* should be reserved for… blackboard ;o)

Comment: "It is true, and this has nothing to do with where x or y live"  If $x = y$ then the value is $0$ and not less than $0$.  $x$ being irrational and $y$ being rational mean $x \ne y$ so the result is *strictly* less than $0$.  But that is the *only* reason I can see for the restriction.  ... Also I guess if $x^2 + y^2 = xy$ then the denominator is $0$. But that implies $xy\ge 0$ so $x^2+y^2\le 2xy$ so $(x-y)^2 \le 0$ which can only occur if $x=y$.. so the restrictions assure neither demom or numer are $0$. But other than that I see no need for the restrictions.

Comment: @fleablood: I mentioned at the beginning that the real condition is that $x$ and $y$  have to be distinct.

Comment: Ah.... so you did.  I was just saying the *only* reason for the distinction that I can tell is to assure they are distinct.

Comment: If it is not stated explicitly, you're right. I don't see any other simple reason either.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

$$(x^2-xy+y^2)^2=x^4-2x^3y+3x^2y^2-2xy^3+y^4$$
Hence your fraction becomes:

$$-\frac{2(x^2-xy+y^2)^2-x^4-y^4}{x^2-xy-y^2}=-2(x^2-xy+y^2)+\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2-xy+y^2}<-(x^2-xy+y^2)$$

The last statement holds because $$x^4+y^4<(x^2-xy+y^2)^2\implies \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2-xy+y^2}<x^2-xy+y^2$$
Provided both polynomials are greater than zero, which they are.